# Terminal issue my desktop has permission -rwxr-xr-x

Tags: macos, unix, permissions, directory, executable

So I did a command
    sudo cp myfile /Desktop

my file was an executable and It changed my desktop to be an executable I need to reset to be a directory with permissions drwxrwxr-x+

Can someone please help Thanks

Comment: That's not a permissions problem, it's a file type problem. A directory ("d") is a different thing than a normal file ("-"). And your desktop isn't /Desktop, it's ~/Desktop. I think you're a bit confused about what happened... Be sure you understand it properly *before* doing anything else to try to fix it.

Comment: Your right it is a file type problem my Desktop Directory at the root of my computer became my executable since my command was cp myFile /Desktop instead of cp myFile /Desktop/ What was in this directory before Is their a way to reset it. I have not encountered any serious issues I would just like to have it back to the way it was?@GordonDavisson

Comment: I still think you're confused about what's happened. Your Desktop directory is not at the root of your computer, it's in your home folder. Try running `ls -l ~` to see what's in your home folder -- if *that* lists a directory named Desktop, your desktop is fine. On the other hand, `ls -l /` will normally not list *anything* named Directory. If `ls -l ~` list a directory named Desktop and `ls -l /` list a file named Desktop, all that's happened is that you've copied the file into an unexpected location with a misleading name.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct command to change permissions on a file/folder is [chmod](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html) or you could reset to default using umask (but I'm not sure about how to use this as well)

Comment: So i tried both chmod 775 Desktop gives me the error "chmod: Unable to change file mode on Desktop: Operation not permitted" and the umask just gives me 0022 Im not sure how to use this command though either

Comment: When you do `ls -l path/to/file` what are the current permissions of Desktop?

Comment: Also, it seems that macosx has lock flag on certain files that you can get rid of using `chflags nouchg path/to/file` and then followed my a `chmod`

Comment: ls -l gives me   -rwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel  1534304 Oct 29 19:34 /Desktop

Comment: So its actually not a chmod issue i accidentally overwrote my Desktop with my executable.Do you know if their is a copy of this somewhere I can replace it with. I still have my Desktop Directory when I type cd but when i move to the root (cd /) i have my executable here

Comment: That's odd, after reading Gordon's comment above and then re-reading the command, the file should have copied into the Desktop folder. That being said, the results of `ls -l` indicates a file--which coincides with your comment...as for a backup, if you're on MacOS and use Time Machine, you might have a backup in there, otherwise you're probably going to have to write up a new question since this one has evolved into something totally different.